# Imperative code in R keeping track of state

Tags: r

A friend of mine has a spreadsheet where she coded a classroom video for various teaching events, which I needed to help her plot. For each recording, she used several video cassettes, and her time codes were relative to each video cassette (ie. they always start on 0). To be able to plot these on a timeline, I needed to convert the times into a relative (continuous) time. The code below works perfectly (and I've solved the problem), however it doesn't look good to me. It looks like the code I used to write in Ruby, before I began playing with R, Haskell etc.

This is not the first time I've come across this kind of a problem - iterating through rows, or lines of text, needing to keep track of several different kinds of "state", etc. I would be curious if this code could be rewritten to look cleaner, more idiomatic.

Example dataset

> ```
> structure(list(code = structure(c(4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 
> 1L, 5L, 2L), .Label = c("CC-NoZZ", "CC-ZZ", "FBP", "KK-NoZZ", 
> "KK-ZZ"), class = "factor"), src = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
> 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("alfred1.mov", "alfred2.mov", 
> "claire1.mov", "claire2.mov"), class = "factor"), class = structure(c(1L, 
> 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("alfred's class", 
> "claire's class"), class = "factor"), start = c(0L, 2L, 6L, 0L, 
> 10L, 1L, 5L, 0L, 6L, 14L), end = c(2L, 4L, 8L, 4L, 12L, 3L, 9L, 
> 4L, 10L, 20L)), .Names = c("code", "src", "class", "start", "end"
> ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
> ```

Example code

```r
src = ""
class = ""
delta = 0
db$corr.start = NA
db$corr.end = NA
db$delta = NA

for(i in 1:nrow(db)) {
    row <- db[i,]
    if(row$src != src) {
      delta = db[i-1,]$end + delta
      src = row$src
    }

    if(row$class != class) {
      delta = 0
      class = row$class
    }

    db[i,]$corr.start = db[i,]$start + delta
    db[i,]$corr.end = db[i,]$end + delta

    db[i,]$delta = delta
}
```

Example output

> ```
>       code         src          class start end corr.start corr.end delta
> 1  KK-NoZZ alfred1.mov alfred's class     0   2          0        2     0
> 2      FBP alfred1.mov alfred's class     2   4          2        4     0
> 3  CC-NoZZ alfred1.mov alfred's class     6   8          6        8     0
> 4  CC-NoZZ alfred2.mov alfred's class     0   4          8       12     8
> 5    KK-ZZ alfred2.mov alfred's class    10  12         18       20     8
> 6  KK-NoZZ claire1.mov claire's class     1   3          1        3     0
> 7      FBP claire1.mov claire's class     5   9          5        9     0
> 8  CC-NoZZ claire2.mov claire's class     0   4          9       13     9
> 9    KK-ZZ claire2.mov claire's class     6  10         15       19     9
> 10   CC-ZZ claire2.mov claire's class    14  20         23       29     9
> ```

Comment: One quick fix would probably be to apply this to the data from each instructor, thus obviating the need for tracking instructor and checking when it changes, etc. However, this is easy because there is no state other than change in instructor. Is there a similar way of turning the time delta into a one-liner?

Answer (score 2):

R encourages vector-based operations instead of loops. But in this case, I don't think there's a good way around tracking the state of `delta`.

This might be a slightly better way to create a vector `delta`:

```
delta <- 0
vdelta <- c(0)
for (i in 2:nrow(db)) {
  row <- db[i,]
  prev <- db[i-1,]
  if (row$class != prev$class) {
    delta <- 0
  } else if (row$src != prev$src) {
    delta <- prev$end + delta
  }
  vdelta <- c(vdelta, delta)
}
```

Based on `vdelta` you can easily create the columns you need:

```
db$corr.start <- db$start + vdelta
db$corr.end <- db$end + vdelta
db$delta <- vdelta
```

Comment: Thanks, some very interesting ideas here, calculating the delta first and then adding it vectorized, and keeping the delta as a vector and then adding it, instead of modifying the data.frame, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you are familiar with the `plyr` package. I think it is well suited for your task. At least it can solve your problem in a very concise manner:

```
library(plyr)
db <- ddply(db, .(class), mutate,
            src.id     = cumsum(c(TRUE, tail(src, -1) != head(src, -1))),
            delta      = cumsum(c(0, diff(src.id)) * c(0, head(end, -1))),
            corr.start = start + delta,
            corr.end   = end   + delta)
```